# Is my URL Redirect safe?

Tags: javascript, security, http, url, redirect

I have the following code which cheaks for `http` and redirects to `https`, Is is completely safe and best way to do it? What are cons of doing it? Why should i do it server side. please i want a through answer because our HUGE comany has implemented it and they won't change it until there is a bug reason to do this. We would like to thank Stackoverflow users on behalf of our comany for halping us becoming secure.

Code [JS]:

```
if (window.location.protocol !== 'https:') {
    window.location.replace(window.location.href.replace(/^http:/, 'https:'))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it isn't safe.
Javascript is client-side language so client can control it, imagine where a client has disabled javascript Or hackers can use XSS bug to disable this function. the best way to do this in server-side is using .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

Another reason to use server-side redirecting is that search engine crawlers can follow this redirects.